# Angular2 production build

Tags: angular, build, production

Trying to find **working** example of **production** build with Angular2.
So far I'm using SystemJs for development and I'm ok with it. Would still like to use non-optimized/minimized/bundled files in dev. But for production I'd like to have bundling (with modules, lazy loading and AOT), minification and tree shaking.
Can't get it working yet. I don't care if it's webpack or jspm or rollup or anything else as far as it does the job. I got somewhat close with rollup but it doesn't like some packages (ng2-bootstrap) I think because of es5/es2015

Comment: I gave an answer that works with `angular-cli` : **Lazy loading + AOT** + minimized bundle and (basic) tree shaking from webpack (not as good as rollup but so much simpler as it's managed by angular-cli. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40788258/2398593

Answer (score 1):

I used to use SystemJS + SystemJS Builder and also tried rollup but faced the same issues.

So I've switched to Webpack and have everything working now.
Here is my repo: https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc

In general:

- I do SCSS build and AOT build with `ngc` **before** webpack gets in: [package.json#L24](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/package.json#L24)
- I have two bootstrap files: [bootstrap.ts](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/lib/bootstrap.ts) (uses AOT factories) and [bootstrap.dev.ts](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/lib/bootstrap.dev.ts) (uses runtime compiler)
- Based on defined by Webpack Define plugin [variable `AOT`](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/build/webpack.prod.js#L98) I switch between these two files: [index.ts#L11](https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/lib/index.ts#L11)
- Webpack 2 claims to  have some kind of tree-shaking from the box but seems it is a bit broken now: [webpack/issues/2867](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2867)

I don't use lazy-loading though.

Also, check [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/).