# Angular2 AOT with Lazy loading Can't resolve [path to lazy module].ngfactory.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-aot

I am trying to convert an App that was already working with Lazy loaded modules into AOT. I am using the @ngtools/webpack toolkit to compile the AOT code, however I am getting into an error that Angular cant find the Lazy loaded module's code as it seems.

```
ERROR in ./src/ngfactory async
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Library/WebServer/Documents/envato-teams/src/ngfactory/src/app/components/container/projects.ngfactory.ts' in '/Library/WebServer/Documents/envato-teams/src/ngfactory'
@ ./src/ngfactory async
@ ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
@ ./src/ngfactory/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
@ ./src/main.aot.ts
@ multi main
```

Worth mention in my app routes definition this project's module is loaded lazily :

```
{
  path: 'projects', loadChildren: './components/container/projects#ProjectModule'
},
```

This is how my setup looks like:

tsconfig :

```
...
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "./src/ngfactory",
  "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
}
...
```

Webpack :

```
new ngtools.AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.aot.json',
}),
```

Main.aot.ts

```
/*
* Providers provided by Angular
*/
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './ngfactory/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

import { Servicesconfig } from './app/services/index';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

In webpack I am compiling ts files with @ngtools/Webpack by doing :

```
// Support for .ts files.
{
  test: /\.ts$/,
  loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'],
  exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
},
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have this very same issue... so far, no fix found...

Comment: the answer I got at the moment in the Angular gitter chanel is that AOT and lazy load do not play well together. It will be fixed soon though https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/88131a08fd39eab5fc49dfce952207ee826bc8ef Its not yet merge but soon it should be released and working in @ngtools/webpack

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling myself with AOT and Lazy loaded modules.

**Choosing one or the other was not really an option for prod build.**

Even tho I really needed those features together, I was not able to get them and had to give up. Until today !

`angular-cli` made a release two days ago : [1.0.0-beta.21](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.21) which **supports AOT and Lazy loading !**

In your angular-cli project :

```
npm cache clean  
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest  
ng init
```

Enjoy !

PS : Big thanks to angular-cli team which made an awesome work here ... !

**EDIT :**
I did some benchmarks :

```
+-----------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
|                       | Main bundle |   Chunk 0    | Scripting | First paint |
+-----------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| ng serve              | 4.5 MB      | Not splitted | 6075 ms   | 5500+ ms    |
| ng serve --prod       | 334 KB      | Not splitted | 5587 ms   | 4750+ ms    |
| ng serve --aot        | 3.3 MB      | 326 KB       | 4011 ms   | 4400+ ms    |
| ng serve --prod --aot | 243 KB      | 18.1 Kb      | 3860 ms   | 4250+ ms    |
+-----------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

(results aren't super good because I have a lot of things opened and 3 monitors and my laptop is in pain ^__^).

**Here's what we can remember from that :**
- The `--prod --aot` build size is **27% smaller** than `--prod` build
- The `--prod --aot` build is **31% faster** when scripting than `--prod` build
- AOT is cool !
- There's probably a bug without `aot` flag because unless I missed something, I couldn't find the lazy loaded chunk I expected and I found the supposed lazy loaded code into the main bundle. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3267) on Github.

Comment: Thanks for this. every think works for me, even lazy loaded modules are getting loaded as expected.

Comment: AOT and lazy loading work well right now if you use the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack like I mentioned in a previous comment this was being fixed at the time I posted the question.

Comment: Can you tell me if it is still necessary to follow config steps outlined in The angular Cookbook: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#overview)? Do I still need to build, bootstrap the module factories? Do you use a separate tsconfig,aot? It looks like for a new cli project that ng build --prod produces the same size as ng build --prod --aot. Im using beta.30 for the cli and angular 2.4.7. Thanks for all the great info.

Comment: Since beta 28 or 30 AOT is now enabled by default when building with `--prod`. So `ng build --prod --aot` and `ng build --prod` are the same :). Try with  `ng build --prod --no-aot` and `ng build --prod` you should see a difference. To know if your project is compiled with AOT, just take a look within your dist and take a look to compiled JS. If you see your templates with ngFor for example, it is not AOT ;)